# Sbt for continuous integration: print stacktrace and exit on error

Tags: scala, continuous-integration, sbt

I'm using Sbt for continuous integration (Bamboo). I want to check all the environment variables are set or get a descriptive error message. I use the following approach:

```
def env(n: String) = Option(System.getenv(n)).getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("Undefined required environment variable " + n))

val mySetting = env("REQUIRED_ENV_VAR") + "..."
```

Instead, I get

```
[error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

Two questions:

1. How to get full stacktrace without need to use 'last' (simple can't do it on Bamboo)?
2. How to tell sbt to exit if project loading failed instead of asking for retry etc?

Comment: [*how to get full stacktrace*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/simple-build-tool/Oubyb6LlZA8/6ihYrzRyTKMJ)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work in case an error occurred during Build object initialization. I get the same error as in original post.

Comment: [how to disable interactive prompt](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/issues/detail?id=80)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sbt will not enable interactive mode if input stream will be "closed" with (such a hacky) trick:

```
cat /dev/null | sbt taskname
```

or if you are not able to use pipes create a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sbt "$@" < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

In sbt v1.3.9 (and probably earlier) there is the `--batch` switch.

```
$ sbt --help
Usage: sbt [options]
  ...
  --batch             disable interactive mode
  ...
```