# Have sbt fail when project loading fails (rather than awaiting user input)?

Tags: continuous-integration, sbt

I'm configuring our CI infrastructure and when project loading fails sbt asks what to do:

```
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

This hangs the build which waits for process to return.

Is there a way to tell sbt to stop without asking what to do when loading fails?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Invoke SBT with the `-batch` option. It will still print the prompt but not actually wait for a reply, instead it will exit with a non-0 status.

Comment: It does not work:

`C:\Users\Jerzy\Workspaces\GitHub\genesis>sbt compile -batch
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\Jerzy\.sbt\0.13\plugins
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\Jerzy\Workspaces\GitHub\genesis\project
C:\Users\Jerzy\Workspaces\GitHub\genesis\build.sbt:11: error: not found: value tru
exportJars := tru
              ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?`

Comment: I tested it on my Mac and it does what I described. For Windows, who knows?

Comment: Ok, maybe sbt runner for Windows is poor. I'll test it on Linux (our CI), if it works there it's ok for me :)

Comment: It doesn't work on Mac OS, either. I'm using `sbt-launch.jar` directly with a simple script that sets `SBT_OPTS` and runs the jar.

Comment: Make sure your script propagates the exit status of the JVM as the exit status of the script itself. As I said, it WFM...

Comment: sbt does have several different start scripts, maybe it's not included in all of them?

Comment: Is this `-batch` argument actually documented somewhere? I only see this [description of "Batch mode"](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Running.html#Batch+mode), but for me running tasks like as described there does not actually suppress the "Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?" prompt, but passing `-batch` explicitly *does* work.

Comment: I just realized `-batch` is implemented in the [sbt-launcher-package](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/blob/d251388f5374af268efd7f48f58e2ac191457654/src/universal/bin/sbt#L86), but *only* for non-Windows. Windows' `sbt.bat` does *not* support `-batch`.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO patching the sbt launcher, so the `sbt` executable, is acceptable only if it has to be done once, ie on a single CI box or on your devenv.

Instead as a trick you can close the stdin on the sbt command:

`sbt < /dev/null`

and by doing so interactive mode will not be enabled, causing it to exit in case of errors.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027455/sbt-for-continuous-integration-print-stacktrace-and-exit-on-error) for a rather similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the underlying JLine terminal type via a JVM argument

```
-Djline.terminal=off
```

and SBT will be unable to prompt you, and simply exit.