# check if sbt can load the build programatically

Tags: sbt, git-bisect

Is there a way to programatically check if a sbt build can be loaded **without running the risk of sbt waiting for user input**? I want to run 'sbt test' as part of an automated git/hg bisect but I got commits where sbt fails to start up because of errors in the build definition and then asks the user what it should do.

See also: [Have sbt fail when project loading fails (rather than awaiting user input)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484166/have-sbt-fail-when-project-loading-fails-rather-than-awaiting-user-input)

Comment: you can run a simple command `sbt version` for example to check that sbt can boot. It's not possible to check if sbt would load without booting sbt itself

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc I have edited my question to hopefully better communicate why this won't do.

Comment: I see. Such problems are usually solved with timeouts if you do run sbt in CI. timeouts will cover other problems also and not just sbt boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `--batch` flag, one can instruct `sbt` to forgo the interactive questioning. It will still exit with an exit code of `1` in case of an error:

```
$ sbt --batch; echo $?
[info] welcome to sbt 1.5.5 (Ubuntu Java 11.0.13)
[info] loading settings for project dl-tools-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /harddisk1/home/user/dl-tools/project
/harddisk1/home/user/dl-tools/build.sbt:63: error: not found: value asdf
asdf
^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[warn] Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? (default: r)
1
$
```